# Burst and rebuild pdf to discard eventual embedded malware

Tags: malware, pdf

[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/how-to-scan-a-pdf-for-malware) question deals with how to scan, while i am curious if my acrobat reader DC is compromised but in an isolated container and i pull out the pdf. Is it safe to disassemble the pdf by `pdftk burst ..` and merge the page.pdf exemplars back together. Does this discard eventual hidden/bad sections? The pdf has mostly images.